# Do there exist integers $m,x,$ and $y$ such that in $\mathbb Z_m$ we have $[x]\neq [0]$ and $[y]\neq [0],$ but $[x][y] = [0]$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

I'm working on discrete math, and this problem is stumping me. I feel like it shouldn't be that hard, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Hint, try $m=$ a product of two numbers $a,b$...

Comment: Yes but if (x)(y) is m then x and y both have to be divisible by m right? But I am trying to find two numbers that aren't divisible by m but when you take the product of them then they are.

Comment: This depends on what $m$ is.  For example, it's false with $m=3$.

Comment: Yes I know but I need to find out where the statement is true

Comment: Marcus, $xy = m $ is almost the definition that $x,y$ [divide] $m$, not is divisible by $m$.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are trying to say, I will keep trying though

Comment: For example, $6=2\times3$

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to find two numbers that are not divisible by $m$, but whose product $xy$ is divisible by $m$. So choose $x$ so that $x$ has some, but not all, of the prime factors of $m$, and $y$ has the others. Neither $x$ nor $y$ will be divisible by $m$, since they are each missing some of $m$'s prime factors, but together the product $xy$ has all of the prime factors of $m$.

Comment: Yes I understand that but I don't know how to know what numbers to use without just trial and error.

Comment: Any composite.  If $m=ab$ and $1 < a < m$ and same for $b$, then $[a][b]=[m]=[0]$ mod $m$.

Comment: @Marcus There is nothing wrong with trial and error when you are looking for counter-examples. Here, you are looking for counterexamples to the statement "modulo $m$, the product of nonzero numbers is nonzero."